# How to getting Xdebug working for php 7.3 and apache (MACOS)

Tags: php, apache, xdebug

I'm trying to get Xdebug (I installed 2.7 with pecl) working for php but getting the following error.

```
php -v
Xdebug requires Zend Engine API version 320160303.
The Zend Engine API version 320180731 which is installed, is newer.
Contact Derick Rethans at http://xdebug.org/docs/faq#api for a later version of Xdebug. 

PHP 7.3.3 (cli) (built: Mar  8 2019 16:40:07) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.3, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.3.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

I've installed the latest version of PHP 7.3 with Homebrew, but Apache is using PHP Version 7.1.23 . I think I'm having an issue because I'm using wrong Zend API version.

php config in httpd.conf is

```
LoadModule php7_module libexec/apache2/libphp7.so
```

phpize gives the following.

```
/usr/local/bin/phpize -v
        Configuring for:
        PHP Api Version:         20180731
        Zend Module Api No:      20180731
        Zend Extension Api No:   320180731
```

I've added the following to php.ini

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/xdebug.so
```

Which exists here :

```
/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303  ls
opcache.a  opcache.so xdebug.so
```

My questions

- how do I get apache to use php 7.3?
- will this solve my Xdebug issue?

Answer (score 3):

After quite a bit more research I found the following tool.

https://xdebug.org/wizard.php

I followed the instructions with some minor changes required for the path and Xdebug is now working.

Answer (score 1):

The **xdebug** site currently only has `64-bit` versions for `PHP 7.3`; the **PECL** site has the `32-bit` versions needed for **XAMPP**.

this will be corrected once `xdebug 2.7` is production, but in the meanwhile the [PECL site](https://pecl.php.net/package/xdebug/2.7.0beta1/windows) is the work around.

Answer (score 0):

You can use, https://xdebug.org/wizard.php.

For Windows,

- Open terminal and enter `php -i`.
- Copy the result and paste it on the text area.
- It will say to download a dll file, Download it.
- Rename downloaded file to ***php_xdebug.dll*** and copy to ***{php-intallation-path}/ext***
- Open ***php.ini*** file and,

**->** Uncomment these, (remove the leading ***;*** only for the ***extension_dir***),

```
; On windows:
; extension_dir = "ext"
```

**->** Add following line,

```
zend_extension = xdebug
```

Rerun the xdebug wizard to confirm,

```
Xdebug installed: 3.1.1
```